# How can I disable all onclick events from elements that are included in an asp:Panel

Tags: c#, jquery

I do have the following piece of code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="PanelID2" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Btn2"/>
    <uc:UserControl runat="server" ID="UserControl2"/>
    <asp:Button runat="server" />
     ...
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Panel ID="PanelID1" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="Btn1"/>
    <uc:UserControl runat="server" ID="UserControl1"/>
     ...
</asp:Panel>
```

I want to disable the all onclick events from all the elements ONLY in PanelID1.
I am trying this, but that disables all the onclick events from all elements.
       `$("[onclick]").removeAttr("onclick");`
How is that possible?Thanks

Comment: What is not working ? Do you have any error in console ?

Comment: @Rayon, Helen wants client-side jQuery code not in console.

Comment: I want to disable only the onclick events that exist in the panel1 not in Panel2. No errors in console.

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi Hehe.. Console.. Developers tool...

Comment: @Rayon, do u mean inspect element?

Comment: Helen, Do share browser rendered markup.. Fiddle will do...

Comment: why do you want to disable onclick event?why not disable button itself?I mean what are u trying to achieve

Comment: `buttonId.Attributes.Add("onClick", "return false;");`

Comment: @Neel Because I have a lot of elements that are inherited

Comment: [link]https://jsfiddle.net/y3mk31d2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$("[id$=PanelID1] *")` selector.

If you use `OnClick` for asp tags such as `<asp:LinkButton  ...>`, it will render to something like:

```
<a id="LinkButton1" href="javascript:__doPostBack('LinkButton1','')"></a>
```

So you should remove `href` attribute by following jQuery Code:

```
$("[id$=PanelID1] *").removeAttr("href");
```

If you still want to remove all `onclick` attribute for children in `<asp:Panel ID="PanelID1" ..>` use `onclick` in `removeAttr` function:

```
$("[id$=PanelID1] *").removeAttr("onclik");
```

Answer (score 0):

As you may have multiple div's in panel so by using jquery

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#Panel1').find('div').removeAttr("onclick");
});
```

Update [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y3mk31d2/2/).